Storing JWT Refresh Token in Shared Mobile/Web Codebase
How should a JWT refresh token best be stored in-browser in a codebase that's shared between a web application and a Capacitor-built iOS & Android application?
On mobile, it's clear what to do -- the backend returns access and refresh tokens and the refresh token is stored securely on the device (Keychain for iOS/KeyStore on Android).
However, it's not so clear to me what to do for web app users.
It seems that I definitely can't securely store the refresh token in browser localStorage because of XSS, but I also can't set an httponly secure cookie directly from the frontend codebase.
If I wanted to try to conditionally set an httponly cookie from the server-side, I'd need for the backend to be reliably able to determine if the API caller is a mobile app or a web user, and I don't believe that is achievable securely.
What is the best way to handle JWT tokens in shared web/mobile codebases without having to have duplicate API endpoints in the backend?
Thanks in advance!

Please see this https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/271157/where-to-store-jwt-refresh-tokens

I have seen APIs where the client, in the login request, specify desired transport mechanism for both JWT and Refresh token. Cookie or header. I think that is a safe solution.
